# Getting error "List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject" when sending data from controller to view

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am trying to send a record from my apex controller to my component but am receiving:

> List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject

Apex Code:

```
        @auraenabled
public static Event_Registration__c isRegistered(Id recordId){
  Id userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    Id contactId = [SELECT ID FROM Contact WHERE OwnerId = :userId].Id;
    List<Event_Registration__c> registrationList = [SELECT ID FROM Event_Registration__c WHERE Event__c = :recordId AND Contact__c = :contactId];
    Event_Registration__c er = (registrationList.size() > 0 ) ? registrationList[0] : null;
    return er;
}
```

JS Controller:

```
    isRegistered : function(component, event) {
     var action = component.get("c.isRegistered");
    action.setParams({ recordId : component.get("v.recordId") });
    console.log('params set');
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            console.log(response.getReturnValue());
            var eventReg = response.getReturnValue();

            if(eventReg != null){
                component.set("v.registered", true);
            }
            else{
                component.set("v.registered", false);
            }
        }
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            // do something
        }
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " + 
                                    errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);       

},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your Query `SELECT ID FROM Contact WHERE OwnerId = :userId` gives more than one records.

you need to update your query like below

```
List<Event_Registration__c> erlist = new List<Event_Registration__c>()
    Id contactId = [SELECT ID FROM Contact WHERE OwnerId = :userId LIMIT 1].Id;
    if(!String.isEmpty(contactId )){
       erlist  = [SELECT ID FROM Event_Registration__c WHERE Event__c = :recordId AND 
       Contact__c = :contactId];
       }

    Event_Registration__c er = (erlist.size() > 0 ) ? erlist[0] : null;
    return er;
```

Comment: You're right, Just noticed that the UserId is the owner of all of my contact records so It was returning multiples